# maximize the revenue in selling Hotels rooms

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

> A hotel has 250 rooms available and the price of each room is $\$175$. For every $\$10$ the hotel increases the price it rents $3$ fewer rooms. Find the price the hotel should charge in order to maximize their revenue.

What i try::

Let $x$ be the number of $10$ dollar price increase room rate. Then room rate is $(175+x)$

And number of room rented is $(250-3x)$

Then total revenue

$$R(x)=(175+x)\cdot (250-3x)$$

$$R(x)=-3x^2-275x+43750$$

Then $$R'(x)=-6x-275$$

For maximum and minimum $R'(x)=0\Longrightarrow x=-\frac{275}{6}$$

I did not understand where i am wrong.

Help me please. Thanks

Comment: The missing piece of information from the problem is how many rooms they rent out at $175. Just because they have 250 rooms doesn't mean they can rent all of them at that price. But with that info not available, I guess assuming its all 250 is likely the best that can be done.

Comment: And the "strange" result shows that if increasing the price by 1\$ causes 3 less rents, they should **decrease** the price to get more people to rent. And decreasing the \$175 initial price by $\$ 275/6 \approx \$45.83\ldots$ is not something unreasonable. Of course, then we come back to my initial comment: If they already rent out all 250 rooms at \$175, there is no incentive to lower the price. And likely the formula only works for integer $x$ anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ is the number of price boosts, then the cost of the room is $175+10x$, not $175+x$.